# error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) doesnt work

Tags: html, asp.net-web-api, runtime-error, visual-studio-2022

I receive this same error when trying to create an ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) when I select "Web Forms" and click Create. I have updated Visual Studio and ran the Repair, I am using the English language and I tried removing the VS cache, but it still gives me that error I reinstalled
what to do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbuCX.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not related to code it is related to opening new projects